# AJAX request from JSON document

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I have a bootstrap website with several cards that contain title, picture and price. I would like to purchase this data from a JSON document. I managed to partially adapt a script found on the Internet, but I do not understand very well.

I need JSON to store the data for each card:

- (card1: picture:src(/ex.png), title: Test, Price: $ 100),
- (card2: picture: src(/ex2.png), title:Test2, Price : $ 120).

I did only this code, but it`s ok only for one card, not for many of these.

Script:

```
  <script>
      function ajax_get(url, callback) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                console.log('responseText:' + xmlhttp.responseText);
                try {
                    var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log(err.message + " in " + xmlhttp.responseText);
                    return;
                }
                callback(data);
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    ajax_get('data.json', function(data,data2) {
        document.getElementById("title", "price").innerHTML = data["title"];


        var html = "<h6>" + data["title"] + "</h6>";
        html += "<p>" + data["price"] + "</p>";  
        html += "<ul>";

        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = html;
         document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = html;
    });
     </script>
```

JSON:

```
card1{
   "title" : "CARD1",
   "price" : "$799.55",
   "image" : src("images/item1.png")
}

card2{
   "title" : "CARD2",
   "price" : "$799.55",
   "image" : src("images/item2.png")
}
```

Screenshot with cards: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZc01.jpg

HTML Code for one card:

```
  <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="card1" style="width: 16rem;">
              <img src="images/landing/item1.png" class="card-img-top" alt="">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h6 id="title"></h6>
                <p id="price">/p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you receive informationa about all cards from your data.json?

Comment: No, i didn`t receive.

Answer (score 0):

You are close in your code, but I will show approach which I use, because it's more flexible.

1. AJAX function (I'm using `Promises` but you can make the result with `callbacks`, `if` statement is for GET request and `else` for others)

```js
function request(method, url, data=null) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.timeout = 2000;
    xhr.responseType = 'json'
    xhr.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4){
            xhr.status === 200 ? resolve(xhr.response) : reject(xhr.status)
        }
    }
    xhr.ontimeout = () => reject('timeout');
    xhr.open(method, url, true);

    if(method.toString().toLowerCase() === 'get') {
        xhr.send(data)
    } else {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept','application/json');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        xhr.send(data)
    }
    })
}
```

2. Render results (Here I am using `async/await` you can use, `Promises ora callbacks` if you want). Remember you must add correct path to the `data.json` file!

```js
async function getTasks(){
    const cards = await request('GET', './data.json');
    if(cards.cards.length){
        cards.cards.forEach(element=>{
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'card';
        div.innerHTML = `<div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="card1" style="width: 16rem;">
                                <img src=${element.image} class="card-img-top" alt="">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                <h6 id="title">${element.title}</h6>
                                <p id="price">${element.price}/p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>`;
          document.body.appendChild(div);
        })
    }
}
getTasks()
```

3. You should change your json file (replace `image` property, from `src("images/item2.png")` to `images/item2.png`) For example:

```
{
    "cards": [
    {
        "title": "TEST",
        "text": "ACADEMY",
        "image": "images/featured/item1.png"
    },
    {
        "title": "TEST2",
        "text": "ACADEMY2",
        "image": "images/featured/item2.png"
        }  
    ]
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kvpqt268/

Comment: I have this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null at getTasks (landing.html:633)

Comment: That's means you have wrong path to your json file. If you logs const cards have you any output?

Comment: I modify your   const cards = await request('GET', './data.json');  to   const cards = await request('GET', 'data.json');  because it`s in the same folder.

Comment: Ok, but ./data.json also means the same folder

Comment: I really don`t know where is the problem.

Comment: I tried this yesterday and everything worked fine. Maybe, you have incorrect json format in data.json file?

Comment: {  
    "cards1": {  
        "title":       "TEST",   
        "text":      "ACADEMY",   
        "image":    "images/featured/item1.png"  
    }  
} 
This is my JSON input

Comment: I edited answer, changed json format and in if statement changed on cards.cards.length

Comment: Error on console: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
landing.html:634 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: cards.forEach is not a function
    at getTasks"

Comment: I have no more ideas why you can't load data file. in getTask should be cards.cards.forEach()

Comment: I edited post and added fiddle, no more I can do it for you :) Good luck!